# How to fix graphics artefacts in Tuxguitar opensource ATI drivers

Tags: ati, graphics, tuxguitar

Since upgrading to 12.10 Tuxguitar (a program I use very often) has graphical glitches and artefacts appearing on the staves on mouse over.

This bug doesn't seem to affect the functionality. Playback is fine and there is no loss of sound quality.

Can anyone confirm this issue or suggest a fix.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here, with my intel onchip graphics, or with the nvidia one.
Already reported here : http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3593773&group_id=155855&atid=797446, but we may confirm it with our graphic cards.

Comment: In fact I just re-tested it now (was using musescore instead...) and it seems to be fixed.

Comment: Still an issue for me on ATI (HD5770) I'll be trying FGRLX this week to see if that has any bearing

Answer (score 1):

Run it from a terminal like this:

```
tuxguitar -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.cairoGraphics=false
```

and it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run it from applications menu:

edit the file `/usr/share/applications/tuxguitar.desktop`, you need to do it with `sudo`

change the line

```
Exec=tuxguitar
```

into

```
Exec=tuxguitar -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.cairoGraphics=false
```

and save.
You can now launch Tuxguitar from the application menu with the given command.